# Play Sprite Kit animations in an array forward and reverse

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, animation, sprite-kit

I'm trying to play a set of separate animations that I have each in their own method although I don't know how to do this in Sprite Kit.

I've set up Previous and Next buttons:

```
 -(void)didMoveToView:(SKView *)view {

   ....

// Add buttons
    SKSpriteNode *previous = [SKSpriteNode   spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"previous"];
    previous.position = CGPointMake(375, 50);
    previous.zPosition = 1;
    previous.name = @"previousButton";
    [self addChild:previous];

    SKSpriteNode *next = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"next"];
    next.position = CGPointMake(670, 50);
    next.zPosition = 1;
    next.name = @"nextButton";
    [self addChild:next];
}
```

And my set of animations in their own methods (eventually there will be 16):

```
- (void)testAnimation1 {

    SKSpriteNode *yellowDiver = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"yellow"];

    yellowDiver.xScale = .75;
    yellowDiver.yScale = .75;
    yellowDiver.position = CGPointMake(380,200);
    yellowDiver.zRotation = -M_PI / 8;

    SKAction *moveYellowDiverX = [SKAction moveToX:450 duration:1.0];
    SKAction *moveYellowDiverY = [SKAction moveToY:300 duration:1.0];
    SKAction *rotateYellowDiver = [SKAction rotateByAngle:(-M_PI / 4) duration:1.0];

    SKAction *yellowDiverSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveYellowDiverX, moveYellowDiverY, rotateYellowDiver]];

    [yellowDiver runAction:yellowDiverSequence];
    [self addChild:yellowDiver];
}

- (void)testAnimation2 {

    SKSpriteNode *blueDiver = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"blue"];

    blueDiver.xScale = .75;
    blueDiver.yScale = .75;
    blueDiver.position = CGPointMake(620,200);
    blueDiver.zRotation = M_PI / 8;

    SKAction *moveBlueDiverX = [SKAction moveToX:550 duration:1.0];
    SKAction *moveBlueDiverY = [SKAction moveToY:300 duration:1.0];
    SKAction *rotateBlueDiver = [SKAction rotateByAngle:(M_PI / 4) duration:1.0];

    SKAction *blueDiverSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveBlueDiverX, moveBlueDiverY, rotateBlueDiver]];

    [blueDiver runAction:blueDiverSequence];
    [self addChild:blueDiver];
}

- (void)testAnimation3 {

    SKSpriteNode *greenDiver = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"green"];

    greenDiver.xScale = .75;
    greenDiver.yScale = .75;
    greenDiver.position = CGPointMake(380,500);
    greenDiver.zRotation = M_PI / 8;

    SKAction *moveGreenDiverX = [SKAction moveToX:500 duration:1.0];
    SKAction *rotateGreenDiver = [SKAction rotateByAngle:(-M_PI) duration:.5];
    SKAction *rotateGreenDiver2 = [SKAction rotateByAngle:(-M_PI/8) duration:.5];
    SKAction *moveGreenDiverY = [SKAction moveToY:385 duration:2.0];

    SKAction *greenDiverSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[moveGreenDiverX, rotateGreenDiver, rotateGreenDiver2, moveGreenDiverY]];

    [greenDiver runAction:greenDiverSequence];
    [self addChild:greenDiver];
}

...
```

Then in the touchesBegan method I want to call each animation method in an array order so that every time I press "next" it goes to the next animation in the set, while killing and removing the previous animation every time a new animation starts. Very much like a photo album with previous and next buttons.

Of course with the Previous button I'd like to do the same, but in reverse:

```
-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    /* Called when a touch begins */

    for (UITouch *touch in touches) {
    CGPoint pointInSKScene = [self.view convertPoint:[touch locationInView:self.view] toScene:self];
    SKNode *touchedNode = [self nodeAtPoint:pointInSKScene];

    if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"previousButton"]) {

        // Play Animation Set in Reverse
        [self testAnimation8];
        [self testAnimation7];
        [self testAnimation6];
        [self testAnimation5];

        //Kill First Set then Play new set in Reverse
        [self testAnimation4];
        [self testAnimation3];
        [self testAnimation2];
        [self testAnimation1];

        //Repeat 16 times
    }

    else if ([touchedNode.name isEqualToString:@"nextButton"]) {

        // Play Animation Set
        [self testAnimation1];
        [self testAnimation2];
        [self testAnimation3];
        [self testAnimation4];

        //Kill First Set then Play new set
        [self testAnimation5];
        [self testAnimation6];
        [self testAnimation7];
        [self testAnimation8];

        //Repeat 16 times
      }
    }
  }
```

Is it possible to store these methods in an array and then increment through them in Sprite Kit with the buttons I created? I don't think I can use the node names because in each method there will be 4 nodes. I need to use the method names. The sample code for the animations is short for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

You can group up your animations or any custom code into `SKAction`s with code blocks and put them into an array:

```
            NSArray *actions = @[
               [SKAction runBlock:^{
                //action1
               }],
               [SKAction runBlock:^{
                //your code here
               }]  
            ];
```

Then you can get an action from the array and run it against the scene, for example.
Or instead of an array of `SKAction`s you could use an array of blocks (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257940/executing-blocks-from-nsarray))